# Return first char in string that is number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to isolate text before the first numeric in a column using T-SQL in SQL Server.

E.g.

```
StreetName 11A-D
```

I would like to receive the result:

```
StreetName
```

My challenge is to find out which char number the first numeric is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: MS Sql has a function called patindex that allows you to combine regular expressions with sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
declare @var nvarchar(100)='StreetName 11A-D';

Select SUBSTRING(@var, 1, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', @var)-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select left(street, patindex('%_[0-9]%', street + '1'))
from (
select 'StreetName 11A-D' street
union all
select 'StreetName' street
) x
```

Result:

```
StreetName
StreetName
```

Comment: the reason for my 'strange' syntax is to prevent errors like other solutions will cause. Also I expect a text like "StreetName" should not result in a blank text

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT RTRIM(SUBSTRING('StreetName 11A-D', 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%','StreetName 11A-D')-1))
```